# How can I read always the newest (last) message from a Kafka Topic that has more then one partition (In my case three partitions)?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

In my .net C# project (with Confluent Kafka library) currently I am using following code to read the newest message from a Kafka topic. But with this code I can read the newest message from the defined partition. But the Kafka server is writing the values of my topic each time to a different partition(My Kafka topic is configured for Partition 0,1,2). So the last (newest) message in the partition is not always the newest message that has been sent to Kafka from the data source side.

How can I adapt my code for three partitions? Is there a simple function for that in Kafka Confluent? Or do I have to read each time from all partitions the message with Offset.End,check their timestamp, and decide which one is the newest one?

```
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = source.Token;
        using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
        {
            consumer.Subscribe("My_Topic");               

            while (var_true)
            {
                TopicPartitionOffset tps = new TopicPartitionOffset(new TopicPartition("My_Topic", 1),Offset.End);
                consumer.Assign(tps);
                var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);                      
                
                Kafka_message_total = consumeResult.Message.Value;

                // additional code to send the message value to an application

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            }

            consumer.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You would just have three consumers yes? Then one will always pickup the newest?

Comment: @MortenBork  Yes my topic is configured for three partitions on the Kafka side. But when I monitor the incoming messages, I see that the message is sometimes coming to P-0, sometimes to P-1 and sometimes to P-3. I don't know how kafka is deciding when to write the incoming message to which partition. So when I use code above I read the last message written to P-1. But this not always the newest one.

Comment: I understand that. And if you run 3 instances of the code base that each read for a partition, one of those instances will pickup the newest message, you just won't know which it is.if you want to control which message  goes into which partition you need to use a partition key in the header of the message.

Comment: If you have a producer sending thousands of events per second, what determines "latest event" for a consumer? Sounds like Kafka may not be the correct tool here, compared to a database record you can just always overwrite and query the most recent data

Comment: @OneCricketeer In my usecase the producer is sending data from a PLC every second. So it should be definitly possible to understand which is the newest message. Of course this is my opinion.

Comment: Sure, but like I said, your consumer shouldn't care it's getting duplicate data, really. You can use that to write to some table, then you query the table to actually get the newest data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you disable consumer group commits and you set AutoOffsetReset=latest, it'll always start reading from the end of the topic, for all partitions.

> do I have to read each time from all partitions the message with Offset.End,check their timestamp, and decide which one is the newest one?

Yes. You can use Offset.End, or seek the consumer to the end of the topic, at any time, or calculate the end offset and subtract one, then seek there.

You simply need a loop of TopicPartition objects for every partition to assign. However, this doesn't parallelize as well as consumer groups using the subscribe api

> see that the message is sometimes coming to P-0, sometimes to P-1 and sometimes to P-3. I don't know how kafka is deciding when to write the incoming message to which partition

The Kafka documentation explains how the producer will partition record keys, based on hash algorithms, or round robined for null keys